# Linkify click text and go to web url

Tags: android, linkify

When the users clicks, it should open the webbrowser and go to https://www.google.com. But the textView's text should be "Click here for the site".

```
    textView.text = "Click here for the site"
    val pattern = Pattern.compile("Click here for the site")
    val scheme = "https://www.google.com"
    Linkify.addLinks(textView, pattern, scheme)
```

How to do this with Linkify?

This solution doesn't work: [Android: Linkify TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746293/android-linkify-textview)

AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Look at this Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746293/android-linkify-textview

Comment: that doesn't work.

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable

Comment: How about just opening the Browser with the wanted URL in TextView.onClick? See this question to see how to open browser in android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917

Comment: @JimClermonts what exactly doesn't work when you try the linked answer? Could you post the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think the `scheme` value you have is incorrect (see [documentation of the 3 parameter addLinks method for more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#addLinks(android.widget.TextView,%20java.util.regex.Pattern,%20java.lang.String))). It should only be the URL scheme, not the entire URL. So, in you example, that would be:

```
val scheme = "https"
```

Although that probably still will not get you what you want since `https://Click here for the site` will not go anywhere. You probably need to add a [TransformFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.TransformFilter.html) and call the [5 parameter addLinks method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#addLinks(android.text.Spannable,%20java.util.regex.Pattern,%20java.lang.String,%20android.text.util.Linkify.MatchFilter,%20android.text.util.Linkify.TransformFilter)). Something along the lines of (not tested, so syntax is probably off):

```
Linkify.addLinks(
    textView,
    pattern,
    null, // scheme
    null, // matchFilter
    new Linkify.TransformFilter() {
        public String transformUrl(Matcher match, String url) {
            return "https://google.com"
        }
    }
)
```

That is basically what is in [Android: Linkify TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746293/android-linkify-textview) that you said doesn't work in your case. So, finally or maybe firstly, you may need to add one or both of these lines:

```
textView.setLinksClickable(true)
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())
```

See the documentation on [`setLinksClickable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLinksClickable(boolean)) and [`setMovementMethod`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMovementMethod(android.text.method.MovementMethod)).

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27929620/1518546) to a related question about clickable phone numbers.